# Android: Google+ Like List Layout

Tags: android

I am interested in displaying a scrollable list of items and want to display them in a fancy fashion, much like the Google+ Android app does. How do I create a styled list like this? Bonus: how do they do that sweet fly-in affect as you scroll? See a screenshot of the UI here:

[image]

Does anyone know of any examples that contain this or any tutorials anywhere?

Comment: Create a custom View. Extend Linear/RelativeLayout. Create such a View(Arranging) and populate it.